# Как проверить OkHttp Client на ошибку?

Tags: android

Как проверить OkHttpClient на ошибку?

Я как понял надо как то сделать это через addInterceptor. Но как именно, как получить код ошибки я не знаю. Другого способа я не могу найти, помогите

Answer (score 2):

Надо создать `Interceptor`, в нём получить результат и проверить его код:

```
final class ExampleRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override 
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if(response.code()!=200){
            //do smth, i.e. throw error
            throw new IllegalStateException("Code is not 200!");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

После, при создании `OkHttpClient` нужно задать этот `Interceptor` так:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new ExampleRequestInterceptor())
                .build();
```